# Reactjs port number still runs on localhost instead of mysite URL

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to deploy a Reactjs application online for the first time. When I run the `npm start` command, it tries to start the app with `http://localhost:3000` instead of `mysite.com:3000` despite the fact I have uploaded the app online.

Here is my `webpack.config`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// copy manifest.json to the path: 'public/build'
// this will allow for the authRequest to see the file at www.example.com/manifest.json
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestAssetPlugin = new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: 'src/assets/manifest.json', to: 'manifest.json' } ]);
const NetlifyHeaderPlugin = new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: '_headers', to: '_headers', toType: 'file' } ]);
const NetlifyRedirectPlugin = new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: '_redirects', to: '_redirects', toType: 'file' } ]);
const IconAssetPlugin = new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: 'src/images/icon-192x192.png', to: 'icon-192x192.png' } ]);
const UglifyEsPlugin = require('uglify-es-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyEsPluginConfig = new UglifyEsPlugin({
    mangle: {
        reserved: [
                    'Buffer',
                  'BigInteger',
                  'Point',
                  'ECPubKey',
                  'ECKey',
                  'sha512_asm',
                  'asm',
                  'ECPair',
                  'HDNode'
                ]
        }
})


const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public/build'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
port: 3000, // most common port
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader!url-loader',
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig, 
    ManifestAssetPlugin,
    NetlifyHeaderPlugin, 
    NetlifyRedirectPlugin,
    IconAssetPlugin,
    UglifyEsPluginConfig
  ]
}
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Tecoba",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "author": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "uglify-es-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what machine/computer you upload/download react app to and run the command `npm run start` it is going to start localhost. You have not deployed the site to a server/host simply by copying the files and running the webpack-dev-server.

The command `npm run start` runs `webpack-dev-server` and this a small localhost development server. It is not designed to serve your web resources once deployed to a hosting machine/instance.

You will need to configure port 80 (expose it) on your host. You will need to update DNS registration for your domain (mywebsite.com) and point to your host IP. You will need to understand the output distribution files that webpack provides you and copy to the right directory on your host server, to serve HTTP requests.

You will have to study how to serve a website in more detail. Start with a simple "Hello World" index.html file using Apache/NGINX/Internet Information Services/Firebase or something else, so many hosting choices.

You are not missing any files.